# Which version of my socket is compatible with the client?

Tags: python, socket.io, flask-socketio

I'm curious,
Which version of my socket is compatible with the client?

Occurrence error,
"The client is using an unsupported version of the Socket.IO or Engine.IO protocols", flask socket.io.js:3511, 400 (400 BAD REQUEST)
"The client is using an unsupported version of the Socket.IO or Engine.IO protocols"

These are my Server current versions:

1. Flask-SocketIO==5.2.0
2. python-engineio==4.3.3
3. python-socketio==5.7.1
4. simple-websocket==0.7.0

Client side:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.8/socket.io.min.js

How can I fix this? Thank you